# How update a field when a record is viewed?

Tags: apex

I'd like to set the field to today's date when the Account Owner views their Account. I've created an extension for this (Accounts are overridden by a vf page), but I'm not sure why it's not working? I've tried a flow too, but have difficulty launching it without embedding it in the vf page.

```
public Account accountObject{get;set;}
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std){
accountObject= [SELECT id,name,ownerid,Field_To_Update__c FROM Account WHERE Id =:std.getId()]; 
string uid = userinfo.getUserId();
string currentOwner= accountObject.ownerid;    
if(currentOwner==uid) 
  accountObject.Field_To_Update__c = date.today();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, @stackasaur, @David-Reed and @nbrown. I couldn't get past the DML problem for my vf page. So I ended up creating a flow to update the field, embedding that flow inside a different vf page, putting that vf page on the Account page layout (my Account vf page accesses the page layout through apex:detail), and setting it's size to 0px (hiding the embedded flow was my original problem and why I turned to apex instead of flows). This seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

You're not performing any DML to persist your changes. You'd have to do

```
update accountObject;
```

after setting the desired field value.

Comment: Thanks! I know this a different question, but it's saying, 'DML currently not allowed' when I load the page. Any ideas?

Comment: @NJW it sounds like you're using a Visualforce _Component_, and not necessarily a _page_. That's a common error to receive in a component if `allowDML` is *not* set to `true` in the component.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're using VisualForce, I'm assuming you're not in Lightning yet.

However, I'm going to provide a solution to this for Lightning using LightningWebComponents for anyone else who searches this (and possibly you when you/your company sees the light... ning)

So this is a very easy thing to do in LWC. No Apex required.

We're going to leverage the updateRecord as well as the uiRecordApi wire adapters.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import FIELD_TO_UPDATE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Field_To_Update__c';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Id';
import OWNER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.OwnerId';
import USER_ID FROM '@salesforce/user/Id';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class trackView extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRecord,{
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [FIELD_TO_UPDATE, OWNER_FIELD]
    }) 
    wiredRecord({error,data}) {
        if (error){
            console.log(error); //custom handler here
        } else if (data) {
            if (data && data.fields && data.fields.OwnerId && data.fields.OwnerId.value && data.fields.OwnerId.value == USER_ID) {
                const fields = {};
                fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
                fields[FIELD_TO_UPDATE.fieldApiName] = Date.now()
                const recordInput = { fields };

                updateRecord(recordInput)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('success'); //custom handler
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error); //custom handler
                });
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

So basically, we just retrieve the current record from Lightning Data Service, which will be very quick since it's already been retrieved by the page and should be in the cache. We look at the ownerId and if it is equal to the current user, we update the record with a timestamp.

To put the component on the Lightning Record Page we just need to define where it goes in the metadata file like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Account</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```